# TestNG dependsOnMethods

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Day3 {

    @Test
    public void webLoginCarLoan() {
        System.out.println("WebLoginCarLoan");
    }

    @Test
    public void mobileLoginCarLoan() {
        System.out.println("MobileLoginCarLoan");
    }

    @Test
    public void mobileSignoutCarLoan() {
        System.out.println("MobileSignoutCarLoan");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "webLoginCarLoan" })
    public void apiCarLoan() {
        System.out.println("LoginAPICarLoan");
    }

}
```

Output:

MobileLoginCarLoan
WebLoginCarLoan
MobileSignoutCarLoan
LoginAPICarLoan

Why WebLoginCarLoan comes before MobileSignoutCarLoan in Output?

Comment: I think that `dependsOnMethods` will make sure `webLoginCarLoan` is executed *before* `apiCarLoan` however not immediately after it perse.

Comment: don't u think the output should be like:  MobileLoginCarLoan  
MobileSignoutCarLoan  
WebLoginCarLoan  LoginAPICarLoan

Comment: You'll have to confirm in the docs but I don't think that the order of tests is guaranteed... and you don't want them to be. You should strive to have tests that are independent of each other where order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG does not execute tests in same order as noted in class. If you think, need to execute tests/@Test methods in specified order then use priority

```
 @Test(priority=1)
```

Also as pointed by Mark "I think that dependsOnMethods will make sure webLoginCarLoan is executed before apiCarLoan however not immediately after it perse"

see in Java Doc https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#dependsOnMethods--

Comment: TestNG by default should execute the Tests in alphabetical Order even if we don't set the priority. Please correct me if I'm wrong. So in a scenario like this why should one set priority?